# How do I get the OS window position in electron?

Tags: user-interface, position, electron

I'm trying to get an electron app to reopen at the same position on the screen as it was when closed for the last time.

To do this I have a config file that records the boundaries of the window when it is closed.

```
function set(settingKey, settingValue) {
  nconf.set(settingKey, settingValue);
  nconf.save();
};

mainWindow.on('close', function () {
  config.set('bounds', mainWindow.getBounds());
});
```

**But** when I restart the app and set the position of the `mainWindow` by specifying the `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` options or with a call to `setBounds`:

```
mainWindow.setBounds(config.get('bounds'));
```

the window appears a bit lower than previously. I figured out that the `y` value I get doesn't take into account the title bar height of the window.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328586/how-to-restore-default-window-size-in-an-electron-app) is similar but the solution results in the same issue.

I have tried:

- `mainWindow.getPosition`
- `mainWindow.getContentBounds` coupled with `setContentBounds`
- `electron.screen.getDisplayMatching(mainWindow.getBounds()).bounds`

to no avail. The first two methods give me exactly the same results. The last one gives `{ x: 0, y: 0, width: 1920, height: 1080 }`.

Does anyone know how to get the OS window position in electron?

If it helps at all, I am on Wayland (Gnome 3.32).

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a long-time unresolved bug on Linux:

[On Linux, returned position of fixed BrowserWindow gets unexpectedly modified](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10388)

For example, the following:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require ('electron');
let mainWindow = null;
function onAppReady ()
{
    let position = [ 200, 100 ];
    console.log ('init:', position);
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow ({ x: position[0], y: position[1], width: 800, height: 600, show: false });
    console.log ('new:', mainWindow.getPosition ());
    mainWindow.loadURL (`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
    mainWindow.on ('ready-to-show', () => { 
        mainWindow.show ();
        console.log ('show:', mainWindow.getPosition ()); });
    mainWindow.on ('close', () => { console.log ('close:', mainWindow.getPosition ()); });
    mainWindow.on ('closed', () => { app.quit (); });
}
app.on ('ready', onAppReady);
```

results in:

Linux Mint:

```
init: [ 200, 100 ]
new: [ 200, 100 ]
show: [ 201, 125 ]
close: [ 201, 125 ]
```

Ubuntu:

```
init: [ 200, 100 ]
new: [ 200, 100 ]
show: [ 200, 100 ]
close: [ 200, 128 ]
```